# Remove Decimal Places with Access SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, decimal

I'm working with MS Access to do some math. I'm taking a Cost and Dividing it by a decimal value to get a Price. I'm using a link table and a access sql query.

SQL Ex

```
Select (cost/markup) As Price From T_Cost;
```

Calulcation Ex. 
1234 / .55 = 2243.6363
1000 / .50 = 2000

I'm trying to figure out a way to remove the decimal places that will work when there are decimals and when there are not.

I was thinking of doing something like this in my Access SQL:

```
Mid("2243,6363", 0, Instr("2243,6363","."))
```

But this won't work if there is not a decimal place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Round.    That's what it's designed for.   However I'm curious.  Why wouldn't you want the cents?

Comment: FYI, the Round function in Access uses "Banker's Rounding."

Comment: The number format I am using is similiar to Japanese Yen so there are no cents. Like 150 Yen would be similar $1.50.

Comment: Ok, you don't need to worry about the decimal places then.  However, in my opinion, you should still use Round instead of Int as that would be more accurate overall.

Answer (score 5):

To remove the numbers after the decimal point:

```
Int(number)
```

or in your case

```
Int(cost/markup)
```

New SQL is:

```
Select Int(cost/markup) As Price From T_Cost;
```

Comment: I wrapped the field name in int() and that works, but it changes the name of the field to `expr1003"

Comment: @bgmCoder `Int(cost/Markup) as NameThatYouWant`.  Look at the third example above.